# Adjust opacity on button inside UIView with opacity at 0.5

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a background image on a ViewController. I also have two buttons inside two `UIView`s.

I want the views to be white with 0.5 opacity, but the buttons should have 1 opacity.

I have set the opacity on the `UIView`s like this:

```swift
myView.layer.opacity = 0.5
```

But this also gives the buttons the opacity of 0.5. When I place the buttons above the `UIView` in storyboard they automatically get embedded in the `UIView`.

How can I get 1 opacity on the buttons?

P.S. I have tried `myButton.layer.opacity = 1`

[image].

[image]

Comment: Just make the background color `0.5` opacity

Comment: Hint: `withAlphaComponent`

Comment: @aheze Thanks. If you post it as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with setting the opacity on the view is that all of the subviews will be affected by the same opacity.

So if you have a view with opacity 0.5 then any subviews will have a maximum effective opacity of 0.5.

To fix this you can give the view an opacity of 1.0 but then set the background color like...

```
view.backgroundColor = Color.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

This will still allow the subviews to have an opacity of 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity can be set in .init method of Color. This should overwrite opacity for that specific button to 1.

```
Button(action: {}, 
        label: {
            Image("<your button>")
                .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 1))                        
})
```

Comment: This answer is for SwiftUI but the question is asking about UIKit.

Comment: Oh, thanks for catching that!